# How to replace image's url from https to http in whole page?

Tags: image, https, userscripts

On a website, although i unchecked SSL Browsing, but image's url still is https, which can't display for some reason, if i replace image's url from https to http, then i can open it.

So it there a script can automatically do this job to display images properly?

Comment: What site? Do you have any code? If you link the images directly with https then they will always load https. Using just //www.domain.com/yourimage.jpg will pick the correct protocol automatically.

Comment: @haxtbh a private tracker; no, i don't have any code; so there is nothing i can do?

Comment: It will be the way the site is configured to serve images. Unless they give an option to change it then you cannot do anything.